# How to force referenceField to be loaded in react-admin?

Tags: react-admin

I'm using react-admin and working according the [demo](https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/#/).

There are project and programs resources and each program has a projectId

I want to create a reference field to project in a different file.

[Here](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/examples/demo/src/products/ProductReferenceField.tsx) an example from the demo.

I customed it for myself, but unfortunately, it doesnot work:(

In using this it shows an empty field in a `datagrid` only when I click on a row to edit it the refrence field is loading and the value apears.

I dont realy understand this code so I dont know why it doesnot work and and How should I corect it.

This is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { FC } from 'react';
import { ReferenceField, ReferenceFieldProps, TextField } from 'react-admin';

interface Props {
    source?: string;
}


  const ProjectReferenceField: FC<
      Props & Omit<Omit<ReferenceFieldProps, 'source'>, 'reference' | 'children'>
      > = props => (
      <ReferenceField
         label="Project"
         source="projectId"
         reference="projects"
         {...props}
       >

        <TextField source="name" />
      </ReferenceField>
  );

 ProjectReferenceField.defaultProps = {

   source: 'projectId',
   addLabel: true,
 };
```

export default ProjectReferenceField;

Could you help me correct my code, and understand it deeper?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you add a `<Resource>` for the `projects` in your `<Admin>`?

Comment: Yes of course. the problem is to show the field.

Comment: I have this reference in a datagrid  I think it's related to lazy loading,
because when you click on a row in the edit table, the data is suddenly loaded and the project names are finally apear

Comment: What dataprovider do you use?

Comment: `simpleRestProvider` tnank you!